# Update state each time after notification is received

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have an app which uses local notifications that contain some data. In this case it's some quotes read from a JSON file.

What I'm trying to do is to read another quote every minute and update it in main screen.

```
void main() {
  runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider<QuotesRepository>(
    create: (context) => QuotesRepository.instance(),
    child: MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var quote = Provider.of<QuotesRepository>(context);
    quote.showScheduledNotification();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        title: new Text('Flutter notification demo'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: Text(
          quote.lastMessage.toString(),
          style: GoogleFonts.clickerScript(fontSize: 40.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the place where provider is defined:

```
class QuotesRepository with ChangeNotifier {
  String? lastMessage;

  QuotesRepository.instance();

  Future<void> loadJson(int index) async {
    String data = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/quotes.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> userMap = jsonDecode(data);

    this.lastMessage = userMap['quotes'][index]['quote'];
  }

  Future<void> showScheduledNotification() async {
    int randomValue = 42;
    await loadJson(randomValue).then((value) => showNotificationBody());

    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> showNotificationBody() async {
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    print("Function called");
    const androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channel id',
      'channel name',
      'channel description',
      icon: 'flutter_devs',
      largeIcon: DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap('flutter_devs'),
    );

    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    );
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.periodicallyShow(0, '365<3',
        this.lastMessage, RepeatInterval.everyMinute, platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: this.lastMessage);
  }
}
```

However this calls the function every second and causes app to crash.
I know it is because I call `quote.showScheduledNotification();` and `notifyListeners()` will cause that it goes inside endless loop.

But how to prevent this? How to load it only once and then update `lastMessage` each time when notification arrives.

For the sake of simplicity I am showing the same quote every time (42).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for an init functionality. If you transform `MyApp` into a stateful widget, you will be able to use the init method of the `stateful` widget. This should solve one part of the problem. You should almost never have init functionality inside a `build` function, since it will be called quite often.

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp();

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var quote = Provider.of<QuotesRepository>(context);
    quote.showScheduledNotification();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        title: new Text('Flutter notification demo'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: Text(
          Provider.of<QuotesRepository>(context).lastMessage.toString(),
          style: GoogleFonts.clickerScript(fontSize: 40.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

PS: For more tips on how to improve the performance of your app, I wrote an article on [my blog](https://jup.dev/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-your-flutter-app/).